# MDX query: how to select between two cubes?

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

is it possible to use conditional select ? i want to implement something like that:

```
if (some_condition)

with ....
select ....
from **cube1**

else

with ...
select ...
from **cube2**
```

the number of columns may vary depending on cube we are using.
is it possible to make this piece of code work? if yes, how to do this with less blood (i mean with minimal cube amendments)?

Comment: I do not think this is possible with standard MDX. From which environment are you executing the MDX? Could you possibly switch the cubes in that environment?